# Invoking service method in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Using Angular and Jasmine I would like to run the service method with some mockup data. Below is the code of my test which uses some working RoomsController trying to run test() method on the RoomsParamsSvc:

```
describe('Rooms Controller', function() { 
    var RoomsController,
        scope,
        location,
        httpBackend,
        RoomsParamsSvc;    
    beforeEach(module('rooms', function ($provide, $injector) {                    
        RoomsParamsSvc = function () { //(1a)
            return $injector.get('RoomsParamsSvc'); //(1b)
        };         //(1c)
        $provide.value('RoomsParamsSvc', RoomsParamsSvc);   //(1d)
    }));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $location, $httpBackend, _RoomsParamsSvc_) {
            // Set a new global scope
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            location = $location;
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            RoomsParamsSvc = _RoomsParamsSvc_;
            RoomsController = $controller('RoomsController', {
                $scope: scope,
                $location: location,
                RoomsParamsSvc: RoomsParamsSvc
            });
        }));
    it('should have test as a function', function () {       
        var t = RoomsParamsSvc.test();
    });
});
```

As far as I understand with the with injector I should be able to use that injected service. Without (1a-1d) I got an error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: RoomsParamsSvcProvider <-
>   RoomsParamsSvc

However now it doesn't work, too. I got an error meaning that test() is not a function:

> jasmine typeerror 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'RoomsParamsSvc.test()')

My service looks like that:

```
var roomsApp = angular.module('rooms', []);
roomsApp.factory('RoomsParamsSvc', function () {
    var factory = {};    
    factory.test = function ()
    {
        return '';
    }
    return factory;
});
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines 1a-1d are not required, as the 'RoomsParamsSvc' is loaded within your 'room' module. But you make a reference to the RoomsController, which is undefined.

```
beforeEach(module('rooms'));
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $location, $httpBackend, _RoomsParamsSvc_) {
        // Set a new global scope
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        location = $location;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        RoomsParamsSvc = _RoomsParamsSvc_;
        RoomsController = $controller(function() {}, {
            $scope: scope,
            $location: location,
            RoomsParamsSvc: RoomsParamsSvc
        });
        console.log(RoomsParamsSvc);
    }));
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gz0JvNPXTMjbgpI8n7s3?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately when I change referrencing 'RoomsController' to function() {} as you wrote...nothing is changing. And by deleting ths lines 1a-1d and wrinting just beforeEach(module('rooms')) I still get the first mentioned error in the question

Comment: Do you use the latest libraries? See the example - there it works - and compare it to your code. Or provide a working plunker yourself.

Comment: Michael - thanks, it helped. I just have some additional code with other services in that controller that I haven't add at the beginning and I was using $provide.value with them. However, even without adding all dependency services I can still test only one service (_RoomParamsSvc_) above. Now I realized it.